# get the execution time of an activity

Tags: android, time, android-activity, launch

I would get the execution time of activity in the foreground (see picture) and the execution time in the background.

[image: screenshot of the execution time of an application. in android 4.2.2]

I've searched in the Android 4.1.2 sources, in classes like "[PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html)" and "[PackageStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageStats.html)" without finding.

can you help me? I would use a service to retrieve the durations of all the activities launched. Thank you !

edit:

I found out how Android search this information but it's complicated.

So I found that Android displays the information in the xml "power_usage_details.xml."

I then found that the activity com.android.settings.fuelgauge.PowerUsageDetail use this xml file.

Then PowerUsageDetail find information in the intent that was passed to start this activity.

The activity which starts PowerUsageDetail is PowerUsageSummary.

PowerUsageSummary find information from com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.

BatteryStatsImpl is extended from the abstract class BatteryStats ...

to conclude, the information is complicated to found, if someone has a better idea, it would help me a lot. thank you !